# How do I stop AudioKit Inputs and Outputs efficiently and definitively?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I've been using `Audiokit.stop()` to reasonable effect, and some minor issues that I'd like to resolve now. With the recent update to Audiokit 4.2, I'm now getting a (very useful) error message from the following code:

```
do {
  try AudioKit.stop()
} catch {
  AKLog("AudioKit did not stop!")
}
```

My error code is this:

```
2018-04-24 16:14:48.099606+0100 MyProject[517:62626] [avas] AVAudioSession.mm:1142:
-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has 
running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
AudioKit.swift:stop():299:couldn't stop session 
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "(null)"
GameScene.swift:update:755:AudioKit did not stop!
```

So my question is - how do I properly stop or pause all inputs and outputs (I/O) as suggested by the error message?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I've tried telling the mic input to stop, setting the output to nil and also asking my trackers to stop and doing the same described above still breaks

Comment: Same problem here, seems to be the only way to stop it is to crash it out

Comment: This one still haunting me - did you get any further in solving this @Chris?

Comment: no solution so far.  As log as it isn't causing crashes for my users I'm ok with the errors for now.  Not happy, just ok.